# How to make an element scroll horizontally without using min-width or an exact fixed width?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, css-tables

I'm trying to create a table which will be responsive,
but to make it simple I want to make it scroll horizontally when it has too many columns.

```css
.fixed-table-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fixed-column {
  width: 140px;
}
.standard-column {
  width: calc(100% - 140px);
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.sc-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 1485px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-table-wrap">
   <div class="fixed-column">
    <div class="fc-content">
    
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="standard-column">
    <div class="sc-content">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In order to have the scroll effect I have to use min-width or a fixed width, but I don't want that because I want the table to be responsive, when it is not exceeding the window's width it should just be natural, and when it exceeds, it scrolls.

To get an even better idea of what my problem is:

What my table looks like:

[image]

More of what my table looks like:

[image]

What happens when I remove the min-width:

[image]

What happens when I have less content WITH min-width:

[image]

What happens when I have less content WITHOUT min-width:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [CSS overflow-x property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) and set an element you've wrapped around your table to "scroll". So with HTML like this:

```
<div id="table-wrapper">
  <table>
       <!-- table content here -->
  </table>
</div>
```

And CSS like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#table-wrapper {
width: 100%;
x-overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
```

Comment: im sorry, i just edited my post, i added a few codes to get an idea of what my problem is.. It can't be simply solve by what you just suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my solution:

```css
.fixed-table-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
}
.fixed-column {
  width: 140px;
}
.standard-column {
  width: calc(100% - 140px);
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.sc-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: max-content;
}
.child {
  width:140px;
}
```